# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent Relationships and Authentication

Tags: model, foreign-keys, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship, laravel-5.1

I have the following tables:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->primary();
        $table->timestamp('start_dt');
        $table->timestamp('end_dt')->nullable();
        $table->integer('dept_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('gravatar')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('dept_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('departments');
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->index();
        $table->integer('organisation_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('manager_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('organisation_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('organisations')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('manager_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('leave_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('leave_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamp('from_dt');
        $table->timestamp('to_dt');
        $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned()->default(1); // pending
        $table->integer('actioned_by_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('leave_type_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('leave_types');

        $table->foreign('status_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('status_types');

        $table->foreign('actioned_by_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(array('role_id', 'user_id'));

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

I have the role_user relationship so that I can authenticate between site admins and general users and so I've created a separate user_profiles table 
to store the general user info becuase the site admin won't necessarily share the same attributes i.e. admin doesn't belong to a dept etc.

My question is whats the correct way then to establish the eloquent relationship between User model and LeaveRequest model. Do I define the relationship
in the User model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,  CanResetPasswordContract {

    public function leaveRequests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LeaveRequest');

    }
}
```

or do I define it in the UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile extends Model {

    public function leaveRequests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LeaveRequest');

    }
}
```

I ask this question because if you look at the foreign key relationship on the leave_requests table, it is 
related to the users table, so personally I would define the eloquent relationship on the Users model. However not all users
will submit leave request for example if your the website admin user.

So would it be better for me to change the table
relationship so that the foreign key user_id on the leave_requests table is related to the user_profiles table instead
and add the eloquent relationship to the UserProfile model?

How would you guys implement this? This becomes very confusing when you are forced to use a single users table to accomodate
authentication and then having to create separate 1 to 1 tables to store the different user type attributes. 
The foreign key relationships become slightly blurred. Normally I'd have separate tables for each type of user i.e users, admin etc - there would be no profile table. But then the authentication become more complex to implement.

Please share your thoughts and how you would go about implementing the above.

Comment: It is the best not to separate the users table even if users (admin, general users) don't share the same profile attributes. Most of this case is 1 to 1 relationship. I will still declare it in user table and assign nullable() type to the field (attribute). As for the departments table, you can assign user_id as foreign key and set it to nullable() as well. Drop the user_profiles table, this just make your brain headache.

Comment: So, the answer is, define the relationship of leaveRequests() in User.php model. You don't need UserProfile model. Did you implement ACL method in your project? I see that you have another foreign key manager_id. That means you have managers table?

Comment: Please share your managers table. why do you have to separate this table from users ? Let me see the structure of your managers table and I will answer all your questions.